# Display A div only on a single page

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, categories

I was working on a word press theme. I created a slider using revolution slider. I need to display it in my category page named wedding. so i pasted the following code into my **header.php**

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider wedding]'); ?>
```

Now as it is in my **header.php** the slider is displaying in all pages.

The category listing page has a class named **term-66** where **66** is the category id.
So i want to display the slider only in that particular page. Some thing like

```
if is class .term-66
{ 
<?php echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider wedding]'); ?>
}
```

Not sure on applying the above logic or some jquery ?? Please help Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it is a custom taxonomy named listing you should use is_tax($tax, $term) instead:

```
if ( is_tax( 'listing', 'wedding' ) )  {
    echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider wedding]');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `is_category` to check if the current page is, in fact, the category you're looking for.

You can pass `is_category` a Category ID, Category Title, Category Slug or Array of IDs, names, and slugs, as per the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category).

```
if( is_category( 66 ) ) {
    echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider wedding]');
}
```

If you're using a custom taxonomy, then you can use `is_tax` in the same way:

```
if ( is_tax( 'listing', 'wedding' ) )  {
    echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider wedding]');
}
```

Comment: my permalink structure is mysite.com/listing-category/wedding/ and the id is 66 . its not working and this is the category url in backend mysite.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=listing&tag_ID=66&post_type=listing_type

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'not working'?  Errors?  Are you certain the category ID is 66?

Comment: Although the previous version of my code would have worked, I have re-written it for simplicity-sake.

Comment: I'm inclined to think the problem is elsewhere then, such as the page you're viewing not being a category (perhaps it's a page within a category?).

Comment: wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=listing&tag_ID=66&post_type=listing_type  thats my dashboard category url im viewing a category listing age

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61486/discussion-between-mikemike-and-melvin-webzer).

Comment: try this to get the cat id. $categories = get_the_category();
$category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;

Comment: it not returning anythin

Comment: Are you certain it's a category?  You might have better look with `is_tax()`.  I have updated the answer with an example.